# Can't use Document in jsoup

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm trying to use jsoup to parse HTML to my android app.
but It seems the error occur at Document.

"Document cannot be resolved to be a type"

"Jsoup cannot be resolved"

Could anyone help me solve this? because I've not found the way to solve it.

```
import java.net.URL;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

URL url = new URL("http://google.com");
Document document = Jsoup.parse(url, 5000);
```

}

Comment: You should call the the parse in a function not directly on the field definition.

Comment: What the error message?

Answer (score 2):

> "Jsoup cannot be resolved"

Because you didn't import the library properly. You have to make a lib folder put the .jar in the folder then, add the build path.